# Active element when is added angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When I select an element the active Css is working stays active and if I click another element active goes to another element but what I am trying now to achieve is when I add a new element automatically that added element to be active. 
I add elements with dialog they are random.
Here is the code for the selected HTML and TS.
If you need more code let me know.

```
selectedIndex: '';

select(project) {
this.selectedIndex = project.id;
}
```

This is on template

```
(click)="select(project)" [ngClass]="{active: selectedIndex === 
project.id, 'project': true}"
```

This is when i save a project

```
 save() {
  const newProject: Project = emptyProject();
  newProject.name = this.newProjectName;
  newProject.id = Math.random().toString();
  newProject.state = this.newState;
  newProject.type = this.newType;
  newProject.category = this.category;
  newProject.subProjectIds = this.subProjectIds;
  this.store.dispatch(new UpsertProjectInternalAction(newProject));
  this.newProjectName = '';
}
```

Comment: I don't really get it. `When I select everything it is working stays active and if I click another element active goes to another element` Please try to add punctuation to your sentence.

Comment: I edited the question, but what I am trying to achieve is when I add something automatically that added element to be active not when i click to be active but automatically.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. Well just set `this.selectedIndex` the same as the element you're creating

Comment: @JeremyThille I am little confused how to do that ?

Comment: I don't really know how you add a project, because you didn't include that part of the code, but you can do something like `projects.push({id : 5, name:"My 5th project"}); this.selectedIndex = 5` and then, the corresponding (new) project will be highlighted.

Comment: @JeremyThille Id of project is rando, i tried like this but didnt work, i edited the question now you can see where a project is saved.

Comment: `this.selectedIndex = newProject.id` then.

Comment: But this is active when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in order to highlight the newly created project :

```
save() {
    // ...
    newProject.id = Math.random().toString()
    this.selectedIndex = newProject.id // Add this line
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working
Here is the css of active.

.project {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex: 1 5 auto;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    padding-left: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    &.active {
      background: white;
    }
  }